# Finding the global minimum

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, normed-spaces, least-squares

Let $f~:~\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ be defined as:

$$f(x)=\left\|\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\3&1\\4&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\7\end{bmatrix}\right\|_2^2$$

I should find the global minimum of this function.  I really have no idea how to start with it. Could anybody give me piece of advice? I know what $\|~ \|_2$ means, but I don't know how to use it with the matrix. Thank you in advance

Comment: The range of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\3&1\\4&2\end{bmatrix}$ describes a plane in $\Bbb R^3$.  What is the shortest distance between the point $(2,1,7)$ and the plane?  How does that relate to the problem as it is originally worded?  [wikilink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_plane).

Comment: It should be mentioned as well, you say you know what $\|v\|_2$ means in regards to a vector but don't know how to use it for a matrix.  Recognize that once having completed all of the arithmetic operations, what is inside of the $\|~~\|_2$ **is** a vector.

Comment: So should I first multiply the first term with (x1 x2) and then substract the (2 1 7) ?

Comment: The answer would be:  
2x1 + x2 - 2
3x1 + x2 - 1
4x1 + 2x2 -7

So then, I'd have ||(2x1+x2-2; 3x1+x2-1; 4x1+2x2-7||2

Comment: if you prefer to approach via differential calculus, yes, that would be fine.  Compute the function as a polynomial in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$ and differentiate.  Alternatively, you could approach via linear algebra and find the point closest on the plane to the point $(2,1,7)$ and find the distance between them.  The square of that distance will be the answer.

Comment: I think I would be inclined to find an equation for the plane in $x,y,z$ terms, and use known formula for the distance of a point from a plane.

Comment: I think the differential calculus is what we're doing right now, so if it's correct, I would stick to this approach. Now I'm one step closer, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Let your function  be equivalent to

$V=(BX-Y)'\cdot (BX-Y)$

$=(X'B'-Y')\cdot  (BX-Y)$

$X'B'BX-2X'B'Y+Y'Y$

Now you can differentiate $V$ w.r.t $X$ and set it equal to 0.

$2B'BX-2B'Y=0$

$B'BX=B'Y$

Thus $X=(B'B)^{-1}\cdot B'Y$

The equation above  is related to the formula in linear regression.